# App crash on [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];

Tags: iphone, ios, storekit

[image: not much report on the crash]

That's all I can get from the crash when I do in the `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
MyStoreObserver * observer = [[MyStoreObserver alloc] initWithContext:self.managedObjectContext andDelegate:self];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

But the weird thing is I have been able to purchase twice in the past and even if I delete the app re-reun everything I cannot escape this pit. It doesn't seems logic. I can alloc init the observer alone without problem and I can call the default paymentQueue without problem but if I try to add the transaction observer to the queue, life stop. It's on ARC and the delegate I added to the observer is not the problem. I know for sure.

I've added an nslog to every method in the observer and none get called before the crash

SOLUTION FOUND

Okay, well it looks like the observer is not retained by the queue and thus the observer needs to be an instance variable.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should add you solution as an answer and mark it as the solution, otherwise the bounty will stay open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, well it looks like the observer is not retained by the queue and thus the observer needs to be an instance variable (or retained in some way).

Comment: instance variable mean you should keep a pointer on your object so that it does not get deallocated. You can simply make a property (strong) that point on your observer

Answer (score 1):

To add an official source to this answer:

Inside the header file SKPaymentQueue.h of the Framework Storekit is the following clear comment:

```
// Observers are not retained.
// The transactions array will only be synchronized with the server while the queue has observers.
// This may require that the user authenticate.
- (void)addTransactionObserver:(id <SKPaymentTransactionObserver>)observer __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
```